# What is involved for storing data in cloud?

Tags: java, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I'm not sure where to ask this so please suggest if I should move this to another stackexchange site

What technologie(s) are sites such as www.jsfiddle.net using in order to store data in the cloud ? Specifically the ability to store a code snippet and then retrieve it later via a URL. Is there a public generic API available for this functionality ?

I've researched cloud offerings such as https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/ but since jsfiddle is free I doubt it is using such a service ?

Answer (score 0):

Via the [jsFiddle about page](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/meta/credits.html#about):

> jsFiddle’s hosting is kindly provided by DigitalOcean.

There is no such thing as a free lunch: someone has to pay for storage. In this case, it's paid for by a third party, not by jsFiddle developers.

As to what they are using to store their data, it's unclear (though you can ask the developers: their names and websites are listed on that page), but the choice will basically be one of the following:

- run a [distributed file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_file_system#Distributed_file_systems) on VMs rented from a cloud provider, or
- use a managed solution, such as Google Cloud Storage that you pointed to, with an API

Either way, you will incur some costs.